# i got a fatal error when using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

i want to get my google docs files from a php file, and i write following codes:

```
require_once ("google/Google_Client.php");
require_once ("google/contrib/Google_DriveService.php");

$client=new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('XXXX');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$parameters=array();
$parameters['q'] = "title contains 'something'";
$children = $service->children->listChildren('root',$parameters);
var_dump($children);
```

but return the following information:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root/children?q=title%20contains%20%27something%27: (404) Not Found'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is not performing the OAuth flow correctly, check the PHP quickstart sample in the Google Drive SDK docs to see how that should be implemented:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

Once your code performs the OAuth flow correctly, you can replace the code in the sample to upload a file with yours to perform a search.

Comment: thx u first,and i have one question more, i just want to get my google docs links from google drive, and using google doc view to display the docs in my personal website, the whole operations are read only, and i  don't want permission request each time when someone browse my site. so how to achieve this? Thx!